# Double images in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I have a rendering issue in IE8 where double images are being displayed. This is the page in question http://www.salterkitchenscales.co.uk/kitchen-scales/

I have read else where that it could be the closing of tags in the wrong order. I don't think that it's the case here.

Could anyone perhaps point me in the right direction?

Page renders OK in Firefox and Chrome.

Thanks in advance.
Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing your product_thumb_bg class in your css, remove the width and height :

```
.products_thumb_bg {
    /* show product image as background */        
    float: left;        
    margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much - I would never have found that!